# Capital M is behaving weirdly in insert-state of evil-mode

Tags: key-bindings, evil

I am observing a strange behavior in evil-mode that I'm unable to figure out what is causing it: In insert-state, pressing "M" does not insert a capital m as expected, but instead gives me the following prompt in the minibuffer (see screenshot 1 below). Strangely, "M" works in visual-state and normal-mode. I have double checked my init.el and I have not accidentally bound M to anything, and all other letters seem to work.

What kind of mode is this showing and how can I debug this?

**Update:** I tried `C-h k M` in insert-state, but this just gave me this: [image: screenshot 2]

**Update:** Turns out this line was the culprit:

> (define-key evil-insert-state-map "M-r" 'evil-paste-from-register)

Is this a bug in evil-mode?

[image: screenshot 1]

Comment: try `C-h k M` in insert mode

Comment: @nichijou: I did, and updated the question with the result.

Comment: What does `C-h k` tell you for `M`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your 'update',

You should use an escape character before the "M" as explained in the [Changing Key Bindings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Key-Bindings.html) section of the elisp manual.

Alternatively, you could wrap the "M-r" in a `kbd` form as explained in the [Key Sequences](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Sequences.html) section of the elisp manual.

(`evil-paste-from-register` is bound to `C-r` by default in evil insert state, but I guess you are aware of that already. Just to be sure...)